# What causes emacs to not display the mini-buffer or window while starting up?

Tags: init-file

I am starting up emacs and I cannot see aynthing in the minibuffer or display window until it starts up.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't understand your question: how can it display something before it has started up?

Comment: What do you want it to display?

Comment: It should desplay the packages that are loading... But it shows nothing.

Comment: This is most likely a problem specific to your init file, so it's going to for others to debug. You can check your \*Messages\* buffer to see if there are any useful clues there. If not, you'll have to do a binary search through your .emacs to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I'm curious about this also - I've tried various things to be able to see the messages as packages are loading with use-package, but something must be interfering with it. I'm on Windows also.

Comment: Fwiw I think I have had this too but I just assumed the system is busy and I didn't care more than that.

Comment: I also have this behaviour. Sometimes I will get minibuffer messages, sometimes it will be blank. Windows also. I never considered it to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason for this?

Yes, because it is busy starting emacs. However, it logs the most important messages in a buffer called `*Messages*` and in the operating systems log or event viewer -- depending on your operating system.

As others have commented above, after emacs has finishing starting up, look into the `*Messages*` buffer or the system's log for any clues to what could be ailing. Post those messages here to help you narrow down the cause.

Lastly, look into starting emacs with --debug [command line option](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs-20.7/html_chapter/emacs_37.html) to get more verbose error messages logged to both the screen (during startup) and to the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: Is this a common issue.  It seems to intermittently affect emacs.

Comment: I am not sure what issue you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, from the menu bar down to the edges of the windows the emacs screen is blank while starting up.  That is what I'm referring to as my "common issue".  It doesn't always occur and is difficult for me to track down.

Comment: Do you see any difference in messages logged in the messages buffer or the system or event logs?

Comment: No.  The message log is the same regardless of if the Emacs screen is blank.

Comment: Something else running on your system is interfering in the screen refresh process. Can't think of what emacs could do differently. What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: what's the value of inhibit-startup-message, or inhibit-splash-screen ? If these are 't' (true) then they are set to not show.  I'm not sure actually what else you're wanting Emacs to display while it loads?  

You said it doesn't always occur, what occurs when it's not blank?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer given by @EmacsUser is right.

To better understand what's happening: Emacs has been around for
a *long* time.  Back in the day, I/O (input/output) with
terminals was very slow.  Because Emacs is incredibly powerful,
it was enhanced so that output to the screen would wait for
internal processing to complete.  That's why your screen
"freezes" when you execute that macro you just defined with an
argument of 12345 -- Emacs is busy working on your buffer(s).
When it's done, Emacs will refresh the portions of your sreen
that need refreshing.

When Emacs starts up, it typically has a lot of things to do.
Unless one of those things blocks, screen updates are essentially
ignored (i.e. they're very low priority), so you won't see what's
happening behind the scenes until Emacs is done processing.